# Place Autocomplete Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I have problem, i cant get correct response with data from San Francisco. Google return data for all USA. I want get street address and coordinate for it.

I create request such as:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=new%20&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=____&components=country:us&location=37.773564,-122.445230&radius=500
```

Genetal [data for create request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete#place_types)

In request i added location and radius fields but it does not work.

Unfortunately I can not specify `components=administrative_area:CA|country:US` i get  `"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"`

Thank you for response.

Comment: Have you seen this?: *Currently, you can use components to filter by country*

Comment: i added this component "components=country:us" but it does not resolve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are requesting the autocomplete-Service, which  returns predictions, not data like geocodes or addresses.

Use a [places-search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) instead.

Comment: It is not best way because i get concrete place such as bank / bar / school not street name or building address.

Comment: then [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is what you need

Comment: can we include &components=country:np in place search

Comment: @ nischal hada: No, componentRestrictions are not supported by place-search